# Control Arduino Pins via ESP8266 Webserver

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I want to program a simple Webserver with an ESP8266 but I want to connect the ESP8266 to an Arduino Mega. I want to connect a LED and a Sensor to the Arduino and control the LED and read the sensor data via the ESP8266 Webserver.
I am a beginner and dont want too complex solutions. It's just a simple school project.
For the Webpage I am sending just some HTML Code, I do not use Blynk or anything like that.

My question is how can I connect the ESP8266 to the Arduino and control it's pins?

Comment: I do not think, that is as simple as you might want it to be. I don't know if its possible, but you will save yourself quite some hassle if you just use the GPIO Pins of the ESP8266 itself (maybe use another breakout board)? If you really need to control the Arduino MEGA from the ESP8266 you will have to use either (Software-)Serial, I2C or SPI and send commands from the ESP8266, that you will then have to parse on the Arduino MEGA in order to Control the pins.

Answer (score 1):

There is a million ways to connect an ESP to an Arduino.

Without any shields or perihperals you can basically use any wired bus that does not require transceivers.

For example I2C or SPI.

With shields or peripherals you can use CAN, LIN, RS232, Ethernet, WIFI, Bluetooth, radio, optical and audio transmission... The list is endless.

You can of course read a sensor with the ESP so an Arduino Mega is not really necessary.

Comment: Can I not just wire the ESP8266 with the Arduino to read out a Pin of the Arduino?

Comment: yes but why the Arduino? if it is a single pin you're interested in, why not attach it to the ESP?  if you insist on the Arduino you need at least two wires. 1 for the signal, 1 for a common ground. but you're very limited in terms of distance and vulnerable to noise that way. so the first thing you need to think about is the distance and why you can't put the ESP where the sensor is.

Comment: It should be as simple as possible, it's just a small project but I want to connect a few more stuff not just only one sensor and I am trying to make it work with what I have here right now. Im using a ESP-01 ESP8266

Comment: if your project lives on a desk you might start with I2C, just google it